# how to write bash script in ubuntu to normalize the index of text comparison

Tags: bash

I had a input which is a result from text comparison. It is in a very simple format. It has 3 columns, position, original texts and new texts.

But some of the records looks like this

```
4   ATCG    ATCGC
10  1234    123
```

How to write the short script to normalize it to

```
7   G   GC
12  34  3
```

probably, the whole original texts and the whole new text is like below respectively

```
ACCATCGGA1234
ACCATCGCGA123
```

"Normalize" means "trying to move the position in the first column to the position that changes gonna occur", or "we would remove the common prefix ATG, add its length 3 to the first field; similarly on line 2 the prefix we remove is length 2"

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I try to use grep and awk but it is very complicated I think it should have a simpler way to do

Comment: Is that "z" in your first text block supposed to be "h"?

Comment: My question may be a bit confusing. So I changed it. The meaning of the first text is that it has an extra C at the position 8 in the new text.

Comment: What you meant by normalizing? I mean what is the algorithm you should implement to get the desired output (especially in the first column of the output)?

Comment: Should not the second line rather be `13   4   `? Is it always the case that column3 equals column1 + something?

Comment: I don't know whether I should call normalizing or algorithm it's not that complicated using human eye but it's really complicated when I try to coding so I thought that I was in the wrong track

Comment: The length in column 2 and 3 must not be zero

Comment: So to "normalize" we would remove the common prefix ATG, add its length 3 to the first field; similarly on line 2 the prefix we remove is length 2, is that correct?

Comment: I would use a full fledged programming language like Perl of Python for this. I know "everything" is doable with every language, but Bash and the Unix toolbox just doesn't feel right for this. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script

```
awk '
    BEGIN {OFS = "\t"}
    function common_prefix_length(str1, str2,    max_len, idx) {
        idx = 1
        if (length(str1) < length(str2))
            max_len = length(str1)
        else
            max_len = length(str2)

        while (substr(str1, idx, 1) == substr(str2, idx, 1) && idx < max_len)
            idx++

        return idx - 1
    }

    {
        len = common_prefix_length($2, $3)
        print $1 + len, substr($2, len + 1), substr($3, len + 1)
    }
' << END
4   ATCG    ATCGC
10  1234    123
END
```

outputs

```
7       G       GC
12      34      3
```

Comment: That's a bit of overkill.  Here's what I came up with. `awk '{for(i=1;i<=length($2);++i)if(substr($2,i,1)!=substr($3,i,1))break;$1+=i-1;$2=substr($2,i);$3=substr($3,i);print}'`

Comment: @tripleee, `i` increments too far: `substr($2,i)` is empty for the first line. You have to put a smarter end condition in the `for` loop.